# Trying to write a data frame to .CSV - Permission denied

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write a datafame to a csv file using the following:

```
fxRollPath = 'C:\Users\stacey\Documents\scripts\FXFiles'
fxData.to_csv(fxRollPath,fxRoll'+ str(index)+'.csv')
```

Where fxRoll is a dataframe

But I get the error:

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\Users\stacey\Documents\scripts\FXFiles'
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: You can run your command prompt as admin.

Comment: elevation shouldn't be required - assuming `stacey` is the current user. if you go to the directory properties of `FXFiles` under security tab if i remember correctly, what are the permissions you see if you select your user? You should have write/modify checked. Boy I don't miss windows at all..!

Comment: do you have an existing copy of the file open in another application like excel?

Answer (score 8):

Just realized, you are actually trying to save to a target directory path instead of file path.

Docs of `path_or_buf` for `DataFrame.to_csv` : "string or file handle, default None. File path or object, if None is provided the result is returned as a string."

So change your code to:

```
fxData.to_csv('{0}\{1}{2}{3}'.format(fxRollPath, fxRoll, str(index), '.csv'))
```

Comment: thanks, I tried the code: fxData.to_csv('{0}\{1}{2}{3}'.format(fxRollPath, 'fxRoll', str(index), '.csv') but got the following error:
  'File "C:\Users\stacey\Documents\scripts\AuctionStrategy_2.2.py", line 69
    def getTimeseriesData(DataPath,columnNum,startDate,endDate):
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax '  Line 69 is the line after the save to csv command.  Has anyone got any thoughts?  Thanks

Comment: i was missing a closing bracket at the end of line. updated my answer above, did you get it to work?

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you need close the first version your csv which now is open

Comment: the answer is too abstract. can you please share your examples where you fixed the issue.

Comment: This seems to be a simple but effective answer. I had faced the same issue of permission. Once I closed the csv to which I was writing, the error disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

I got this problem too. Not sure if you have the same situation as me.

I had the same filename in the same directory and I wanted to override the old csv file. Instead of overriding the old file, I deleted it and then save it to solve this problem.

```
        os.remove('filename') 
        df.to_csv('filename.csv')
```