write.csv command is creating a folder and not a .csv file in pyspark
I am working through a book chapter in pyspark and the write.csv command is creating a folder, rather than a .csv file.
I am working in jupyter notebook rather than the shell and the following command is creating a folder:
results.coalesce(1).write.csv("./simple_count_single_partition.csv")

I've worked through the following example, taken from "Data Analysis with Python and PySpark" by Jonathan Rioux
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import (
    col,
    explode,
    lower,
    regexp_extract,
    split,
)

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName(
    "Analyzing the vocabulary of Pride and Prejudice."
).getOrCreate()

book = spark.read.text("./data/gutenberg_books/1342-0.txt")

lines = book.select(split(book.value, " ").alias("line"))

words = lines.select(explode(col("line")).alias("word"))

words_lower = words.select(lower(col("word")).alias("word"))

words_clean = words_lower.select(
    regexp_extract(col("word"), "[a-z']*", 0).alias("word")
)

words_nonull = words_clean.where(col("word") != "")

results = words_nonull.groupby(col("word")).count()

results.orderBy("count", ascending=False).show(10)

results.coalesce(1).write.csv("./simple_count_single_partition.csv")


That's how DataFrameWriter.csv() works. If you want a single csv then read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33174443/how-to-save-a-spark-dataframe-as-csv-on-disk

This question is similar to: How to save a spark DataFrame as csv on disk?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

the write.csv() is still writing the data to a single csv. it should be inside the folder named "simple_count_single_partition.csv". spark will give a random name to the csv though. and, that's by design.

Convert your dataframe to pandas and then save to CSV:
results.coalesce(1).toPandas().to_csv("./simple_count_single_partition.csv")


Yes I tried that but I received a "permission denied" error which doesn't make sense

@DaveDiggler, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36634469/trying-to-write-a-data-frame-to-csv-permission-denied
